# Creating world file for Gazebo with xacro

Tags: ros

I'm trying to generate random boxes in a world file for Gazebo simulator.
I know how to create a model sdf, and how to include it from the world file.

Now I want to create different sizes of boxes in the world file using xacro and width/height parameters.

I can't get it work.
Please help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, what I am going to describe is an alternative design that may serve as a workaround to your question and it goes like the following steps :

**Step 1** : *Create your object as a well parametrized xacro file 
(all parameters are included in the same file)*. A good tutorial (too long to be included in here) on HowTO this could be found in the [Xacro URDF page](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20Xacro%20to%20Clean%20Up%20a%20URDF%20File).

**Step 2** : *include your xacro in a gazebo-robot launch file and test it's working fine till now*.
an example of this can be found [in PR2 description here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_roslaunch):

```
<!-- Convert an xacro and put on parameter server -->
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find pr2_description)/robots/pr2.urdf.xacro" />

<!-- Spawn a robot into Gazebo -->
<node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-param robot_description -urdf -model pr2" />
```

**Step 3** : *if you consider your object as a robot to launch in a gazebo world, a solution to pass parameters for its creation (in xacro file) could be by passing the needed arguments using `prefix:=$(arg value)` like the following([explained in here](http://answers.ros.org/question/38956/pass-parameters-to-xacro-in-launch-file/))*:

```
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find my_robot_description)/urdf/my_robot.urdf.xacro' prefix:=$(arg ns)" />    
in the xacro file you can simply get the passed argument using $(arg prefix)
```

This way, you can create your object in an xacro file, launch it in Gazebo using a ROS launch file and tweak it according to your needed value.

Furthermore, ROS launch files can pass parameters as well to its contents, so, your values can be also updated directly through command line :

`roslaunch your_package launch_file.launch a:=1 b:=5`

or stored in a [parameter server](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/rosparam) for retrieval at launch time.

Hope that Helps, Cheers !

Comment: Thanks for that. What if i have a different situation: I have a list of predetermined "size"s and "pose"s, and I want to generate world file includes them. I want the file to be as clean as possible, so I want to use single model file and include it many times and only specify size/pose for each?

Comment: a way to proceed is using step 3 and roslaunch parameters in a bash script with a for loop, this is discussed [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/12016/easier-way-to-launch-nodes-and-roslaunch/) and examples on the loop can be found [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/). please edit your question with updated results and questions. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add this little ROS node in your .launchfile to convert a .xacro to a .whatever:

```html
  <node name="xacro" pkg="xacro" type="xacro" args="--inorder -o $(find YOURPKG)/PATH_TO_FILE/NAME.sdf_OR_WHATEVER_EXTENSION_YOU_WANT_FOR_FINAL_FILE $(find pkg)/PATH_TO_FILE/NAME.sdf.xacro" />
```

Basically you run the xacro node with to 4 arguments. The last two are the paths to your files. First the name of the file you are going to create (and where) and second the .xacro original file. In my case I added the find pkg option but this is obviously optional.